# Does the CircleCI API command "New Checkout Key" work for type "github-user-key"?

Tags: api, github, github-api, github-pages, circleci

I am trying to use CircleCI's REST API to create a "New Checkout Key" of type "github-user-key".

If I run :

```
curl -X POST \ 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-d '{"type":"deploy-key"}' \ 
https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/myOrg/myPrj/checkout-key?circle-token=8e9c47...etc
```

I get :

```
{ 
"public_key" : "ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABA . . . pRYe+9SHcZFs4n \n", 
"type" : "deploy-key", 
"fingerprint" : "b0:cd:e8:77:ef:00:d5:da:62:b7:fc:d9:9e:84:f7:f1", 
"login" : null, 
"preferred" : true, 
"time" : "2015-11-20T14:57:43.379Z" 
}
```

If I run :

```
curl -X POST \ 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-d '{"type":"user-key"}' \ 
https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/myOrg/myPrj/checkout-key?circle-token=8e9c47...etc
```

I get :

```
{ 
"message" : "Invalid checkout key type (valid types are deploy-key and github-user-key)" 
}
```

If I run :

```
curl -X POST \ 
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \ 
-d '{"type":"github-user-key"}' \ 
https://circleci.com/api/v1/project/myOrg/myPrj/checkout-key?circle-token=8e9c47...etc
```

I get :

```
{ 
"message" : "{\"message\":\"Not Found\",\"documentation_url\":\"https://developer.github.com/v3\"}" 
}
```

I suspect the documentation for the command is incomplete.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: This *did* work in the past.... we've used it before. However, I'm getting the same error you're getting. The error message indicates it's a mismatch on CircleCI's end in communicating with Github. I'd get on a CircleCI support chat and report it to them.

Comment: @criswell Thanks for the ratification. I asked on the support chat last night.  This morning, the reply was, "The reason you don't require any GitHub key, only a Circle API key, is because we should already have access on your account to do this."  Wut????  I elaborated on my original question and hope to get a more useful answer some time today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be able to add a user key to your project, CircleCI needs permissions from GitHub to add SSH keys to your account. You can grant it permission by visiting **Project Settings > Permissions > Checkout SSH keys** for any of your projects and clicking on **Authorize w/ GitHub**. After doing this, you should be able to generate a checkout key of type `github-user-key` for any of your other projects using the `curl` command you demonstrated.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for surfacing this—we are filing a bug with your report. Sorry for the confusion with the first answer we sent you, we didn’t understand the context well enough.

Comment: Cool!  Thanks!  I am liking CircleCI more and more :-)